# Error no mapping column in Entity 6 DB first design

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a legacy mvc application which I cannot rewrite. There's a stored procedure which all the returns column names of table `A` except for `ID`. (Note, it actually does not select from table A, but just happens to return the same column names). I wish to call the stored procedure (via SQL query), and assign the results to a variable of class A. However, I get a `System.Data.Entity.Core.CommandExecutionException` saying  *A member of the type 'ID' does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name*.

My code is as follows:

Class A

```
namespace LegacyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class A
    {
        [NotMapped]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SOId { get; set; }
        public string SODesc { get; set; }
        //... 
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel rb)
    {
        var query = this.buildQuery().ToString();

        // The results returned by the query contain all members of A except for ID
        IEnumerable<A> goals = db.Database.SqlQuery<A>(query);

        // Exception occurs here
        List<A> goalList = goals.ToList();
        rb.goalList;
        return View(rb);
    }
}
```

Properties of ID in .edmx designer

[image]

I was under the assumption that the `[NotMapped]` or `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation should ignore the ID? The reason I'm doing this is because the user would be filtering the queried dataset, in which the filtered results would then be inserted into table A. As table A using has a PK ID which is auto incremented, I would like the IDs to be `NULL` upon insertion. I've updated my Model from the entity designer but I still get the error. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity

Comment: I meant do return ID, but use Identity attribute to indicate that this is something which shoud be touched by DB.

Comment: 1) you need to return ID from sql 2) you do NOT need [NotMapped] attribute 3) you DO need Identity attribute. Having all these, db will return you whole entity with ID (and entity framework needs key for each object), database will update ID with autoincrement, and EF will then fetch that ID.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sp doesn't return an ID (and I'm unable to modify it). That being said, is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Lanorkin and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492888/4896260), I was able to come up with a solution that worked. I created base class which contains the subset of the fields called by the stored procedure. The class generated by Entity then extends the base class adding ID. To aid with adding to the database, I created a helper constructor to initialize all the members of the base class with the Entity. My code is as follows:

```
namespace LegacyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    // My base class
    public partial class A
    {
        public Nullable<int> SOId { get; set; }
        public string SODesc { get; set; }
        //... 
    }
}
```

My class generated by Entity

```
namespace LegacyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class B : A
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to assign all members of base class A to B
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseClass">the base class</param>
        public B(A baseClass) : base()
        {
            foreach (var prop in typeof(A).GetProperties())
            {
                this.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(baseClass, null), null);
            }
        }
        public int? ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel rb)
    {
        var query = this.buildQuery().ToString();

        // The results returned by the query contain all members of B except for ID
        IEnumerable<A> goals = db.Database.SqlQuery<A>(query);

        IList<B> goalsToInsert = new List<B>();
        // Create a new List of Objects of type B. 
        // Constructor allows for all members of A to be assigned to B 
        goals.ToList().ForEach(x => {goalsToInsert.Add(new B(x));});
        db.B.AddRange(goalsToInsert);
        db.SaveChanges();

        rb.goalList = goalsToInsert;
        return View(rb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read entity from database, you can use *projection* - a class which contains just the fields you select.

When you insert / update entity, this entity should be mapped in model, always have key etc.

Technically projections can be any classes and not required to be included in model.

I see following choices for your case:

1. Create absolutely separate `Dto` class and use it for `SELECT`ing using stored procedure you have
2. If stored procedure selects subset of original fields and do not introduces new fields - you can organize classes hierarchy like `Entity : Dto`, and use `Dto` for `SELECT`ing, and "whole" `Entity` class for updating
3. If fields *mostly* match, but there are differences - you can introduce `Base` class with common fields, and then create `Entity : Base` and `Dto : Base` for appropriate cases.